# Java Swing SearchBox Model

Tags: java, swing

I need search Box using Java Swing which shows suggestion from database when we type letters if we click on any suggestion it will perform some action . if it possible in java swing please give the source code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DefaultComboBoxModel` , and the output will be like that.

[image]

[**Try this**](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/autosuggest.html)

---

In this code you will find `countries` array , so you need to take this array from your database